# bootstrap 5 navbar toggler icon not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried the navbar toggler in mobile view and it is not showing the list.

here is my code, I have a CSS file linked in the head tag and other script tags inside the body tag

```html
<body>

    <header class="bg-info">
        <div class="row text-white">
            <div class="col-md-6 xs-9 ">
                <h2>yahiya muhammed</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-3  my-auto">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                  
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end " id="navbarSupportedContent">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">prjects</a>
                          </li>
                       <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">contact me</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                     
                    </div>
                  </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
```

I tried to mobile view and the navbar toggler is not showing items

Comment: you can get lot's of idea from Get started with Bootstrap link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toggle button has incorrect attributes.  Change `data-toggle="collapse"` to `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` and change `data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"` to `data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"`.

Working snippet below:

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="bg-info">
    <div class="row text-white">
        <div class="col-md-6 xs-9 ">
            <h2>yahiya muhammed</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-3  my-auto">
          
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
              
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end " id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">prjects</a>
                      </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">contact me</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                 
                </div>
              </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```